# Dynamic game configuration

Tags: configuration

I am not sure how that systems type called, so I try to describe what we want and it will be great if someone can advise…

We have online game with client/server architecture. The game has some configs and this configs must be available for change. Simple example is that we have monster_id 10 with attack_power 15 and our game designers while trying to improve balance, changed attack_power value to 14, so next time, when clients load game, they also load Monster config and monster with id 10 have attack_power 14.

For now, we use Google Sheets as configs “frontend”. We add some custom scripts that allow load this sheet as json on our backend that will compress it, update revision and store in our DB. And when game client booted, backend sends this compressed configs from DB. But the problem is that architecture lack off functionality… I mean, that is hard to ever add simple validation for some rows of sheets, because we need to use google macros and they (as I know) even don`t allow to load external js libraries…

Ofc we can write our backend&frontend for this, but I think that it is as making a bicycle… So, my question is there any system that work with “dynamic configuration” as described above and allow users to customize it, write extension etc.?

Comment: It sounds like you want to send the config to the client, and let the client make the calculations on its own. Never trust your client. The client should basically send its input to the server, and the server should tell the client what happened based on that input. What happens when users find out they can load the config, and alter a monster to have 0 attack power?

Comment: @Peethor Yes, we allow client to make calculation to "hide" delay that will exist if client wait answer from server. So, client make calculation and send it "move" to server, that will validate this "move". Also, this attack power must display in monster info, so allow client to load configs decreased total number of request as client don`t need to ask server about monster info when user open "monster info window"

Comment: @Peethor and anyway, even if all info about monster info only exist on server, we need some tool for our game designers to manipulate this values and question was if there some tool already exist or for any game we must write it from scratch?